# PartialFunction vs Function1 syntax-wise

Tags: scala, akka

As part of my journey learning Scala and then Akka, I'm trying to understand how one can spot a `PartialFunction`.

In the "Programming Reactive Systems" course, there is this example for an Actor:

```
class Toggle extends Actor {
  def happy: Receive = {
    case "How are you?" =>
      sender ! "happy"
      context become sad
  }
  def sad: Receive = {
    case "How are you?" =>
      sender ! "sad"
      context become happy
  }
  def receive = happy
}
```

It's a pretty simple one and I would say I understand what it is trying to do. The thing that I don't understand is that `happy` and `sad` are of type `Function1` (or at least that's my belief) and yet they can play the role of a `PartialFunction` (`receive` needs a PartialFunction).

And even worse than that, based on the [Akka documentation](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/Actor.html), `receive` is supposed to return a `PartialFunction` (not being one):

> abstract def receive: Actor.Receive
>
> Scala API: This defines the initial actor behavior, it must return a
>   partial function with the actor logic.

But as far as I can tell, `happy` and `sad` are not returning a `PartialFunction`, they are one.

To wrap up my questions:

1. Is there a way to spot a `PartialFunction` against `Function1`?
2. Am I reading the example wrong? Isn't the `receive` a `PartialFunction` that returns `Unit`? If the answer is yes, then why the documentation says the `receive` should return a `PartialFunction`?

**[UPDATE]**

Based on the answer I've got from @Brian McCutchon, now I know that the `receive` method is supposed to return a `PartialFunction`. But that doesn't help with my confusion at all! Consider the following scenario:

```
def someFunction(): Receive = {
  //Instantiates and returns a Receive object
}

class Toggle {
  def happy: Receive = {
    case "How are you?" =>
      someFunction()
  }
}
```

My question is, how does the Scala compiler know if the given code should be expanded to this:

```
class Toggle {
  def happy: Receive = {
    return {
      case "How are you?" =>
        someFunction() // <-- The returned object of this function call is dismissed
    }
  }
}
```

Or this:

```
class Toggle {
  def happy: Receive = { // <-- Starting point of happy's body
    case "How are you?" =>
      someFunction() // <-- The Receive object is returned by this method
  }
}
```

Or more importantly, how am I supposed to know which expansion will happen? And I thought modern programming languages are supposed to be more readable!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `happy` and `sad` are of type Function1

No, they are methods that return [`Receive`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/Actor$.html#Receive=PartialFunction[Any,Unit]), which is a type alias for `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]`. The type annotation you gave shows this return type. Partial functions can use the same lambda syntax as `Function1` (and other [SAM types](https://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/#lambda-syntax-for-sam-types)), in which case they are distinguished only by context (in this case, your type annotation).

> `receive` is supposed to return a `PartialFunction` (not being one)

You're confused on terminology. `receive` is a method, not a `PartialFunction`, as you declared it with `def`. It returns a `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]` (a.k.a `Receive`). This should also clarify your confusion over `happy` and `sad`.

This is a reasonable source of confusion, as the syntax is so concise as to make it look like `receive` and the `PartialFunction` it returns are one thing. It might help to realize that your code could be expanded to this (though I wouldn't advise it in practice):

```
class Toggle extends Actor {
  def happy: Receive = {
    return {
      case "How are you?" =>
        sender ! "happy"
        context become sad
    }
  }
  def sad: Receive = {
    return {
      case "How are you?" =>
        sender ! "sad"
        context become happy
    }
  }
  def receive = {
    return happy
  }
}
```

Per your update, the first expansion is correct. The second one doesn't make sense, as method bodies can't start with `case`, which should clue you in that you're dealing with a lambda. To sum up: if a block starts with lambda arguments (e.g. `x =>`), or it starts with `case` and isn't a `match` block, it's a lambda.

Comment: Thanks, but you've missed my first question. I updated the question to explain it better.

Comment: Updated to explain how to detect a lambda.

Comment: So, that's what I was missing. I didn't know that a pattern matching block with missing `match` could only be a lambda! But still, this is an awful syntax. Whoever designed this syntax has never developed software.